# When to use FormGroup vs. FormArray?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

[FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup):

> A **FormGroup** aggregates the values of each child FormControl into one
> object, with each control name as the key.

```js
const form = new FormGroup({
  first: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
  last: new FormControl('Drew')
});
```

[FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray):

> A **FormArray** aggregates the values of each child FormControl into an
> array.

```js
const arr = new FormArray([
  new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
  new FormControl('Drew')
]);
```

When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

FormArray is a variant of FormGroup. The key difference is that its data gets serialized as an array (as opposed to being serialized as an object in case of FormGroup). This might be especially useful when you don’t know how many controls will be present within the group, like dynamic forms.

Let me try to explain by a quick example. Say, you have a form where you capture a customer's order for Pizza. And you place a button to let them add and remove any special requests. Here is the component's html part:

```html
<section>
  <p>Any special requests?</p>
  <ul formArrayName="specialRequests">
    <li *ngFor="let item of orderForm.controls.specialRequests.controls; let i = index">
      <input type="text" formControlName="{{i}}">
      <button type="button" title="Remove Request" (click)="onRemoveSpecialRequest(i)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="button" (click)="onAddSpecialRequest()">
    Add a Request
  </button>
</section>
```

and here is the component class defining and handling special requests:

```js
constructor () {
  this.orderForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
    lastName: new FormControl('Drew'),
    specialRequests: new FormArray([
      new FormControl(null)
    ])
  });
}

onSubmitForm () {
  console.log(this.orderForm.value);
}

onAddSpecialRequest () {
  this.orderForm.controls
  .specialRequests.push(new FormControl(null));
}

onRemoveSpecialRequest (index) {
  this.orderForm.controls['specialRequests'].removeAt(index);
}
```

FormArray offers more flexibility than FormGroup in the sense that it is easier to manipulate FormControls using "push", "insert" and "removeAt" than using FormGroup's "addControl", "removeControl", "setValue" etc. FormArray methods ensure the controls are properly tracked in the form's hierarchy.

hope this helps.

Comment: what if you are trying to edit forms?  How do you iterate and add controls?

Comment: How would you refactor this into components?

Comment: Is it possible to add objects with key:value into the form array instead of just values?

Comment: How can we set a form label name? is there any option to set while form control is initialized? since form dynamic we couldn't set it's value.

Answer (score 38):

In order to create a reactive forms, a parent `FormGroup` is a must. This `FormGroup` can further contain `formControls`, child `formGroups` or `formArray`

`FormArray` can further contain array of `formControls` or a `formGroup` itself.

**When should we use formArray?**

Please read this beautiful [post](https://medium.com/aviabird/complete-angular2-guide-reactive-forms-in-depth-part-1-21a8e2428904) which explains the usage of `formArray`

The interesting example in that blog is about the trips `formGroup`

The structure of trips `formGroup` using `formControl` and `formArray` would look something like:

```
this.tripForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [name, Validators.required],
     cities: new FormArray(
       [0] ---> new FormGroup({
           name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
               places: new FormArray(
                  [0]--> new FormGroup({
                      name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                         }),
                      [1]--> new FormGroup({
                         name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
                      })
                  )
              }), 
       [1] ---> new FormGroup({
           name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
           places: new FormArray(
               [0]--> new FormGroup({
                   name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
               }),
               [1]--> new FormGroup({
                   name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
               })
               )
      }))
})
```

Do not forget to play with this [DEMO](https://ashish173.github.io/ng2-forms/trip/create), and notice the usage of array for `cities` and `places` of a trip.

Comment: @scopchanov It might not have much explanation with the text, but the form structure representation does give some idea. Let me know if there is anything that we can add to improve the answer :)

Comment: Well, if someone says "explanation", then I expect to see exactly that. With all my respect, your answer is very close to a "link only answer" according to the SO definitions, because right where it gets to the point, i.e. _When should we use formArray?_, a link to a blog post is provided, without citeing any significant part of it. You have indeed posted some code, but again no explanation whatsoever. It would have made a huge difference, if you had cited both rules from this blog post.

Comment: @scopchanov Sure, I will make this answer better when I have some time to add.

Answer (score 11):

From: Anton Moiseev's Book “Angular Development with Typescript, Second Edition.” :

When you need to **programmatically add (or remove)** **controls** to a **form**, use **FormArray**. It’s similar to **FormGroup** but has a **length variable**. Whereas **FormGroup** represents an **entire form or a fixed subset of a form’s fields**, **FormArray** usually represents a **collection of form controls that can grow or shrink**.

For example, you could use **FormArray** to allow users to enter an arbitrary number of emails.

Answer (score 0):

From angular documentation you can see that

> FormArray is an alternative to FormGroup for managing any number of
>   unnamed controls. As with form group instances, you can dynamically
>   insert and remove controls from form array instances, and the form
>   array instance value and validation status is calculated from its
>   child controls. However, you don't need to define a key for each
>   control by name, so this is a great option if you don't know the
>   number of child values in advance.

Let me show you their example and try to explain how I understand this. You can see source [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pxxgkrxpylye?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.ts)

Imagine a form witch has following fields

```
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: ['']
    }),
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });
```

Here we have `firstName`, `lastName`, `address` and `aliases` All field together are form group so we wrap everything in `group`. At the same time `address` is like a subgroup so we wrap it in another `group` (You can look at template for better understanding)! Every form control here hes `key` except `aliases` and it means that you can push in it values as much as you want like simple array using `formBuilder` methods like `push`.

This is how I understand it, hope it helps someone.