# How to attach ngModel with dynamic number of checkboxes in Angular?

Tags: angular, checkbox

I have a list which contains dynamic number of checkbox's, each is having id attribute.

```
<li *ngFor='let i of someArray'>
<input type="checkbox" id={{i}}>
</li>
```

I can assign each input checkbox if they are known previously by [(ngModel)] to those many number of variables.

But how to attach dynamic number of checkbox's with variables while preserving the concept of Two-Way binding.

I am using @angular/core 2.4.10.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use `FormArray` for this.

```
import {FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  checkboxes: this.fb.array([])
});
```

Then you can loop from the controls:

```
<li *ngFor='let control of form.checkboxes.controls; let i = index'>
  <input type="checkbox" id={{i}} [formControl]="control">
</li>
```

Then you can get the value by doing `this.form.get('checkboxes').value`.

Comment: There is one edit which I have done to make it work.    <li *ngFor='let control of form.get("checkboxes").controls; let i = index'>
  <input type="checkbox" id={{i}} [formControl]="control">
</li>   Since you are accessing checkboxes using index, my problem is still same-how to uncheck/check these checkboxes when some conditions satisfies in background?

Comment: @techcomp You just grab the form control and call `control.setValue(false)`, where `control` is a variable which holds the control.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike @Chrillewoodz said, you're not forced to use the Form Array, although I recommend you to use it. Otherwise you can do

```
<li *ngFor='let box of someArray; let i = index'>
    <input type="checkbox" [id]="box" [(ngModel)]="someArray[i]">
</li>
```

Comment: Is there some way to not access it by index ?

Comment: No, it throws an error because Angular tries to access dynamically created variables. You **need** to use the index if you don't want to use formArray.

Answer (score 0):

[FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) can be used when you don’t know how many controls will be present or when you have dynamic elements in form.

FormArray is well explained in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray?answertab=active#tab-top)