# How to get values from dynamically repeated forms in FormGroup on Typescript?

Tags: javascript, forms, typescript, ionic2

Thanks for reading my question!

I'm using Ionic 3 to create an app. In this app, there is a page with up to 200 equal forms with an input each, like this: [ionic page with repeated forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYfz1.png). It was me who typed "input3","input4" and so on to denote where the input spaces are.

**The user chooses how many of these forms there will be on the page** on a configuration modal, so I **cannot** create these forms statically.
So, I managed to create these forms on HTML using the code below:

```
      <form>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let y of rowCount|times" text-center align-items-center>
          <ion-col align-self-center col-2>{{y}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col text-center align-self-center col-4><ion-input id='input{{y}}' 
            formControlName="input{{y}}" [(ngModel)]="inputy"></ion-input></ion-col>
          <ion-col align-self-center col-4>{{status}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col align-self-center col-2><button
            id= 'button{{y}}' ion-button small icon-only>
            <ion-icon name="brush"></ion-icon></button></ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </form>
```

I used a `Custom Pipe` called `times` to repeat the rows as many times as the variable `rowCount` is equal to.

I managed to get the `id`, the `formControlName` and the `ngModel` of each form dynamically, but **ONLY on HTML**.

How can I get the values of each of these dynamically created `formControlName` on the Typescript code? Also, is it possible to get the values from the dynamically created `ngModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re mixing reactive forms (eg. `formControlName`) and template driven forms (eg. `ngModel`). I’d suggest reading through the Angular docs on those before going further.

If you choose reactive forms, you’ll want to use a `formArray` as they’re meant for exactly this. `ngFor` exposes the index to the template, and your `formControlName` will simply be the index.

You can set the value of reactive forms with `patchValue` and `setValue` from your ts.

I don't mean to suggest that you *should* use reactive instead of template driven, just that you shouldn’t mix them. If you’re more comfortable with template driven, it’s totally fine. The docs go into the pros and cons of each.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks adamdport! I managed to make it work. When everything is working the way I want, I will upload my code here to show how I did it. Also, the aswer of @Usman in this post help me a lot as well: [When to use FormGroup vs. FormArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I managed to do what I wanted to do.

On `home.ts`, I created the `FormArray`inside a `FormGroup`, as shown below:

```
  this.homeForm = new FormGroup({
  bicos: new FormArray([])
  });
```

Then, inside your repeat/add function, you use this code:

```
 addForm(){
 (<FormArray>this.homeForm.controls['bicos'])
 .push(new FormControl(null));
 }
```

And, on home.html, the part that matters looks like this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="homeForm"> 
 <ion-row formArrayName="bicos" *ngFor="let item of 
 homeForm.controls.bicos.controls; let i = index" >
 <ion-col text-center align-self-center col-5>
 <ion-input #inputs formControlName="{{i}}" type="number"></ion-input>
 </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
 </form>
```

As I said in my comment above, you can also find an approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423792/9319353).