# How to use reactive forms within ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

An array of users can have multiple elements (users). In a template, I iterate over this array and add a form for each element. Right now each form binds to the same form group values. If I fill out the form for the first user, submit buttons of all the forms become enabled. How to point each form to the unique formGroup or unique variables?

component:

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
...
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
 form: FormGroup;
 @input users: any[];

 constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}
 ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
   address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
   });
 }

 add() {
   if (this.form.valid){
     // code
   }
 }
```

Template:

```
 <div *ngFor="let user if users">
  {{user.name}}
    <form [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="add()">         
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Address:</label>
       <input formControlName="address" class="form-control">
       <label>Phone:</label>
       <input formControlName="phone" class="form-control"></input>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>    
    </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**To solve your problem you have to use `formArray` as follows:**

**In the component:**

```js
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    usersForm: FormGroup;
    errorMessage : string;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.usersForm= this.formBuilder.group({
            users: this.formBuilder.array([
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    address: [null, [Validators.required]],
                    phone: [null, [Validators.required]]
                })
            ])
        });
    }

    initUserRow(): FormGroup {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            address: [null, [Validators.required]],
            phone: [null, [Validators.required]],
        });
    }

    addUserRow(): void {
        const usersArray=
            <FormArray>this.usersForm.controls['users'];
        usersArray.push(this.initUserRow());
    }

    removeUserRow(rowIndex: number): void {
        const usersArray= <FormArray>this.usersForm.controls['users'];
        if (usersArray.length > 1) {
            usersArray.removeAt(rowIndex);
        } else {
            this.errorMessage = 'You cannot delete this row! form should contain at least one row!';
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.errorMessage = null;
            }, 4000);
        }
    }

}
```

**In the view:**

```html
<form *ngIf="usersForm" [formGroup]="usersForm" (ngSubmit)="createUsers()">
    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr class="text-center">
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody formArrayName="users">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of usersForm.controls.users.controls; let $index=index" [formGroupName]="$index">
            <td style="min-width: 120px">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="address"/>
                <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['address'].touched
                             && usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['address'].hasError('required')">
                    Please enter address!
                </div>
            </td>

            <td style="min-width: 120px">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="address"/>
                <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['phone'].touched
                             && usersForm.controls['users'].controls[$index].controls['phone'].hasError('required')">
                    Please enter phone number!
                </div>
            </td>

            <td style="width: 100px">
                <button (click)="addUserRow()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button (click)="removeUserRow($index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Hope now your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 4):

With reactive forms, you define the data structure to hold the form data in your code. In your example, you define it with `this.form`. But your form definition only has one address control and one phone control. So you've told Angular to only store one address and one phone.

To allow for multiple address/phone sets, you need a FormArray as mentioned by @DavidZ. As its name implies, a FormArray allows you to have an array of form values.

In your example, your FormArray would be comprised of a FormGroup with one entry for each user. The FormGroup would be comprised of the set of FormControls: the address and the phone.

**Form Component**

This example has a name and an array of addresses, but should give you a general idea:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        addresses: this.fb.array([this.buildAddress()])
    });
}

buildAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
            addressType: 'home',
            street1: ['', Validators.required],
            street2: '',
            city: '',
            state: '',
            zip: ''
    });
}
```

You can find the complete code for this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/tree/master/Demo-Final-Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FormArray`, [this article](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) gives a nice summary.

Also be sure you understand the [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray) between `FormArray` and `FormGroup`