# Angular generate dynamic FormGroup with custom formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I want to create a dynamic formGroup based on json like this:

```
  const LIMITS: Limit[] = [
  {
    id: 'limit1',
    value: 1000,
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    id: 'limit2',
    value: 500,
    disabled: true
  },
  {
    id: 'limit3',
    value: 5000,
    disabled: true
  }
]
```

Using formArray from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray) response works fine, but I will lost my `id` information which I need to match edited values. Is there way how to generate dynamic form with my custom `formControlName` name?
[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdgmdr) is stackblitz ecample based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray) response.

**EDIT**

---

I used approach with `FormGroup` w but on init I get an errors

```
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'limits -> limit1'
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'limits -> limit2'
Error: Cannot find control with path: 'limits -> limit3'
```

I know that when inputs are 
See [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teek5f) stackblitz example.

**EDIT**

---

I have found solution by defining `limits` then used `setControl` in data subscription.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      limits: this.fb.group({})
    })

    this.limits$.subscribe((limits: Limit[]) => {
      this.form.setControl('limits', this.addLimits(limits));
    });

  }
```

See stackblity [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7noaj)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `id` field as a key, then simply use `FormGroup` instead of `FormArray`, and use `addControl` and `removeControl` instead of `push` and `removeAt` to keep your form dynamic.