# Dynamic social links in Angular 8 using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to render a list of dynamic social links in my Angular app. The data comes from the database like this:

```
// User model
{
    ...
    socialLinks: [
       { name: 'Site1', url: 'https://site1.com/user' },
       { name: 'Site2', url: 'https://site2.com/user' },
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This is how the form group is created in the component:

```
public async ngOnInit(): Promise<any> {
    const userResult = await this.userService.getLoggedInUser();

    if (userResult) {
        this.userSettingsForm = this.fb.group({
            displayName: [this.user.displayName, Validators.required],
            bio: [this.user.bio, Validators.maxLength(256)],
            location: [this.user.location],
            socialLinks: this.fb.group(this.user.socialLinks)
        });
    }
}
```

And the template:

```
<form [formGroup]="userSettingsForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    ...
    <div *ngFor="let socialLink of user.socialLinks; let index = index" formArrayName="socialLinks">
        <div class="position-relative">
            <img [src]='"/assets/icons/" + user.socialLinks[index].name + ".svg"' 
                [alt]='user.socialLinks[index].name + " page"'>
            <input class="form-control" [formControlName]='index'
                [value]='user.socialLinks[index].url'>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The fields are populated with the url as they should, but I'd like the form value to reflect the same structure as the data coming from the database. Currently, if I edit any of the fields, the value of the input goes from the original object to just a string. I tried subscribing to the `socialLinks` controls for changes and remapping the values, but that seemed redundant.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1man1u)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as `socialLinks` is an array - you would need to reflect it with [FormArray class](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and items of the array would be [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) instances. We could achieve it with an existing form builder, simply mapping over links:

```
socialLinks: this.fb.array(this.user.socialLinks.map((l) => this.fb.group(l)))
```

after this step, we would have form array with for groups which represents structure of **socialLink**, so that is why we also need changes in html to cover it(from stackblitz):

```
<div class="position-relative" [formGroupName]='index'>
    ...
    <input class="form-control" formControlName='url'>
</div>
```

now each `[formGroupName]` would be and an *index* and `formControlName` would represent the field we want to work with

Hope this helps :)

Also, there are some handy explanations here:

https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

[When to use FormGroup vs. FormArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray)

P.S. consider using `socialLink` inside `*ngFor` such as it is the direct reference to `user.socialLinks[index]`

Comment: Perfect! Yes I tried a few variations but it looks like I was missing the `fb.group()` inside the form array. Sometimes Reactive Forms can be as annoying as they are useful :)
Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)