# Set array value into formgroup

Tags: angular, multipartform-data, form-data, formbuilder

```
this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({
      os: [null, [Validators.required]],
});

const osType= ['Android', 'Ios']
```

I tried

```
this.formgroup.controls.os.setValue(osType)
```

Result

```
os: ['Android', 'Ios']
```

Expected Result

```
os: 'Android'
os: 'Ios'
```

I need to send data from using formdata. i have tried with setValue but i got different result than i expect. can someone tell me how to do for the expected result. Thank in advance

Comment: You need to create Array of FormGroup, May be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray

Answer (score 0):

you need a FormArray of FormControls. Typicall you transform the array in FormControls using map

```
this.formarray = this.formbuilder.array(
    this.osType.map(x=>this.formbuilder.control(x))
);
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x51mcg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you want to use setValue, remember that the formArray must be the same number of elements that the array before use setValue

NOTE: if you want to manage a formArray that is NOT inside a formGroup you need create an auxiliar function

```
  getControl(i)
  {
    return this.formarray.at(i) as FormControl
  }
```

Then you can write

```
<div *ngFor="let control of formarray.controls;let i=index">
    <input [formControl]="getControl(i)">
</div>
```

NOTE 2: Before Angular 10 you can make in others ways: using the formArray like a formGroup or using the variable of the loop to indicate the control, but nowadays this is the way to control a formArray "standalone"